# Output is very unorganised of beautifultable

Tags: python, python-beautifultable

[output is like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou1Ly.png)
i displayed result from database in a tabular form using BeautifulTable python. but the result is unorganised.

```
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                 database='testdb',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='Pooja@123')
    cur= connection.cursor()
    sql = "select ip,ports,services from output where date=now()"
    number_of_rows = cur.execute(sql)
    table=BeautifulTable()
    table.set_style(BeautifulTable.STYLE_DOTTED)
    table.column_headers=["ip","ports","services"]
    table.column_alignments['ip'] = BeautifulTable.ALIGN_LEFT
    table.column_alignments['ports'] = BeautifulTable.ALIGN_LEFT
    table.column_alignments['services'] = BeautifulTable.ALIGN_RIGHT

    row=cur.fetchall()
    for r in row:
        table.append_row(r)

    print(table)
```

Comment: What does it mean `unorganised`? Show the output

Comment: output is given in the link.. kindly check. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou1Ly.png

Comment: It seems it's only because of the variable-width font.

Comment: then how to fix it?

Comment: @PoojaBanoula _"then how to fix it?"_ You fix it by either choosing a monospaced font in the GUI application you're using or using displaying the data in some other place where this is the default (e.g. terminal).